# Error "database in use" when Installing Dynamics AX 2009 Team Server

Tags: installation, dynamics-ax-2009

I've set up Team Foundation Server to be used as VCS for Dynamics AX 2009.

Now I tried to install the AX 2009 Team ID Server (on the same server as TFS), and get the following error during setup, no matter what I do:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.  If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. 
>   If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> Cannot drop database "AXTS" because it is currently in use.

The error is kind of stupid, since the AX Team Server installation created the database itself!
I'd say some error did occur, and the installation is trying to drop the database (without success, since the installation itself is using it).

Can anyone help me to get the AX Team Server installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh swell, I scrapped SQL Server 2008, used SQL Server 2005 instead, now it works.

I got no idea why it did not work with SQL Server 2008, though.